# File transfer to the server CURL

Tags: php, curl

Trying to upload a file to server using `CURL`

The query is formed as:

```
$postdata = array(
'FileToLoad' => "@".$this->file."; filename=\"$this->filename\";",
'fileId' => $this->fileId);
```

`$this->file` contains the full path to the file on the server `/var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/tmp/file.pdf`

Send:

```
if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, ".ASPXAUTH=$this->token;");
$out = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
}
```

The request is successful, but data is in `$_POST`, and I really want to see in `$_FILES`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: There is something wrong with the syntax you posted, you should even get a parse error. Please post the real code

Comment: You should use CURLFile to upload files using Curl here you go: http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php; :)